# How to perform a search in CASSANDRA for a parameter that is in a certain range

Tags: python, cassandra, range

I am new to CASSANDRA, therefore question may be too simple.

I am trying to perform query on a table that have a Partitioning key consisting of two components: refid and partid. The problem I encounter is that the number of partid can be large (and different for different refid). The query that I have now is like:

```
SELECT * FROM contigs WHERE refid=29179863 AND partid IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21);
```

What I would like to do is to have a query that look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM contigs WHERE refid=29179863 AND partid IN range(0,21);
```

Is there a way to do it? I would like to avoid creation of the query string in python first and executing it in Cassandra later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `IN` for partition key in `select` queries can lead to performance issues.
Specify `refid` as partition key but `partid` as **clustering key** and you will be able to do range queries by `partid`

```
CREATE TABLE contigs ( 
    refid int,
    partid int,
      ... other fields...
    PRIMARY KEY ((refid), partid) 
);
```

Query `partid` range:

```
SELECT * FROM contigs WHERE refid=29179863 AND partid >= 0 AND partid < 21;
```

But notice, cassandra have limitation of 2 billions rows inside a partition key so in this case, you can't have more than 2 billions partids for a refid.